# IHTMLDocument2.write()

Tags: c#, html, mshtml

I'm writing an application that checks some data on a we page, so I try to write the entire html in a IHTMLDocument2 but the program locks on the write() method. I mean it doesn't stop, it just locks. Here's the code:

```
result = doHTTP_Request(uri, data, _userA, cType, "POST", cookie);
String _res = (String)result[0];
cookie = (CookieContainer)result[1];

IHTMLDocument2 doc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
doc.write(_res);
```

Comment: You should use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ instead

Comment: Have you dumped the value of `_res` somewhere and verified that its sane?

Comment: I could be wrong but from what I remember, you have to first navigate to a blank page and then write your custom string into the document. Just try this and let us know if it helps.

Comment: yes, _res has the entire html page that I need, but write still locks

Comment: i tried to write a blank page before writing _res into doc, it still doesn't work

Comment: well it could be stucking on downloading large resources such as image or javascript. to exclude those you need to write an ActiveX container and use ambient property to change download control setting. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(v=vs.85).aspx#Controlling_Download_and_Execution

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but you can try the following:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = new HTMLDocument() as IHTMLDocument2;
DisableDebuggersAndNotification(true);
doc.write(_res);
DisableDebuggersAndNotification(false);


    private void DisableDebuggersAndNotification(bool setValue)
    {
        string val = null;
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", true))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                val = (setValue) ? "yes" : "no";
                key.SetValue("DisableScriptDebuggerIE", val, RegistryValueKind.String);

                val = (setValue) ? "yes" : "no";
                key.SetValue("Disable Script Debugger", val, RegistryValueKind.String);

                val = (!setValue) ? "yes" : "no";
                key.SetValue("Error Dlg Displayed On Every Error", val, RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
        }
    }
```